# First and Last class within product loop issue

Tags: woocommerce

Im running a simple custom product loop. The issue im having is that the LAST class is set at the wrong time. It seems the loop_index is not correct. I should have 4 products per row, but after the 3rd the last class is set. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Thanks

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 40
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
  endwhile;
} else {
  echo __( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a filter (`loop_shop_columns`) to overwrite shop columns.

```
function loop_columns() {    
  return 4;   
}

add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999); //overwrite shop column filter

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => 40
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
  endwhile;
} else {
  echo __( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

make sure to call `add_filter` in relevant function only. Otherwise it will affect to all archive/category pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
woocommerce_reset_loop();
```

Add this before args